# Сохранение значения переменной из multiprocess.Process после его завершения

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Имеется процесс запущенный через `multiprocess.Process`, в нём изменяется значение свойства класса, как я могу сохранить это значение после завершения процесса?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно использовать `multiprocessing.Manager()`